# How to get string parsed in html properties on a Vue js x-template?

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js, vuejs2

a thing like this won't be correctly parsed. `{{ item.post_permalink }}` will not be substituted by the passed-in text, while `{{ item.read_label }}` will be correctly parsed.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="news-template">
   <a href="{{ item.post_permalink }}" class="read-more">{{ item.read_label }}</a>
</script>
```

how to solve? It seem's it's somewhat related about being inside an html property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `v-bind` to dynamically bind the attribute values not `{{ }}`

So do it like this:

```
   <script type="text/x-template" id="news-template">
       <a v-bind:href="item.post_permalink" class="read-more">{{ item.read_label }}</a>
    </script>
```

or shorthand for `v-bind` is `:` like this:

```
   <script type="text/x-template" id="news-template">
       <a :href="item.post_permalink" class="read-more">{{ item.read_label }}</a>
    </script>
```